# Visualizing n-dimensional arrays

Tags: macos

What software can I use to create a 1/2/3-dimensional array visualization by only inputting some numbers? In addition to existing software, anything like javascript/python packages is also welcome.

I want to show the exact numbers on the visualization automatically:

[image]

I would prefer a solution which can read numbers from files, but it's also fine for me to manually input the numbers.

This software does exactly what I want 
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=arrayvisualizer
but this seems not to be maintained and can't be downloaded anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion of a python method [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-art-of-effective-visualization-of-multi-dimensional-data-6c7202990c57). It uses histograms and maps the data in 2-d. Includes source code.

Answer (score 1):

For C# or C++ this [Visual Studio extension "Graphical Debugging"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamWulkiewicz.GraphicalDebugging) provides array data visualization of variable contents while stopped at a break point.

[image]